# Passing one partialview's data to another partialview

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a Main View, and 2 Partial Views.

1 Partial View has:

- DropDownList
- Textbox
- Add button

2nd Partial View has:

- Two Textboxs
- In which one is displaying value of 1st partialView's DropDownList
- and second displaying TextBox's value of 1st Partial view.

The functionality I am trying to achieve, when a `Click Event` occurs on `Add Button`, the data within `DropDownList` and `TextBox` should appear within the 2nd partial view `TextBoxes` (In addition the amount of `TextBoxes` is dependent on how many `Clicks` the `Add Button` received). I'm currently confused on how I can pass the data and preserve it.

Here is the code below, for the first partial view (including a `DropDownList` and `TextBox`)..

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("AddServices", "Controller1", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
   {%>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
<div class="edit-set">
<label>Nature of Service:</label>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.DropDownList("ddlServiceType", (SelectList)ViewData["ServiceType"] as SelectList, "--Select Nature Of Service--", new { onchange = "FillServiceType();" })%>
    <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)%>
    <label>Comment:</label>
    <input type="text" id="comment" />
</div>
<input type="submit" value="+ Add More Service(s)" onclick="InsertService()" name="submitButton"/>
</div><input type="submit" value="Done" name="submitButton"/>
<% } %>
```

After user has inserted needed services, All the textboxes values which are in 2nd partial view must be insert into database. My problem is that I must maintain all values but without inserting data into DB. It'll be inserted after use clicks Done button.(I can use table also in second partial view, but that table's value must be available to insert in DB.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1
Try render action instead of render partial view.

If the values from the DropDown and the Textbox have to save in the DB first that means you have to submit the data first.

So the action would go and fetch the required data from the DB to render the second partial view and return it.

see render action: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("AddServices", "Controller1", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
   {%>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
<div class="edit-set">
<label>Nature of Service:</label>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.DropDownList("ddlServiceType", (SelectList)ViewData["ServiceType"] as SelectList, "--Select Nature Of Service--", new { onchange = "FillServiceType();" })%>
    <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)%>
    <label>Comment:</label>
    <input type="text" id="comment" />
</div>
<input type="submit" value="+ Add More Service(s)" onclick="InsertService()" name="submitButton"/>
</div><input type="submit" value="Done" name="submitButton"/>


<%= Html.Action("MyAction", "Controller", new {ID = Model.id}) %>


<% } %>
```

Comment: I have to insert data after Done button Clicked. Not each time it clicks +Add More Service(s).

Comment: But in your example they both submit your form.. I don't understand what you are trying to do.. please be more clear.

Comment: ONE SUBMIT IS FOR ADDING MULTIPLE SERVICES TO 2ND PARTIALVIEWS'S TEXTBOXES. and another one for Done. That is adding all the services which are added to second partialview, have to submitted to DB. And I am managing multiple submit button in switch case.

Comment: okay, clicking the 1st submit would adds a text-box to the second partial view without inserting anything to the db ? and the second submit actually send a list of all service to the controller ?

Comment: so use $('body').append("<input type="text" name="MODEL[0].name" />"); to add a new textbox

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25588/discussion-between-djit-and-mortalus)